# Cassandra model paging with REST API

Tags: python, api, model, cassandra

I have model as.

```
# File: models.py
from uuid import uuid4

from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns


class StudentModel(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'students'
    id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name = columns.Text(index=True, required=True)

    def __json__(self):
        return {'id': str(self.id),
                'name': self.name}
```

I wrote bottle app which serve data from this model.

```
# File: app.py
from bottle import run
from bottle import Bottle, request, HTTPResponse

from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table

from models import StudentModel

API = Bottle()

# Create Connection
connection.setup(hosts=['192.168.99.100'],
                 default_keyspace='test',
                 protocol_version=3)

# Sync database table to create table in keyspace
sync_table(StudentModel)

@API.get('/students')
def get_all_students():
    all_objs = StudentModel.all()
    return HTTPResponse(
            body={'data': [x.__json__() for x in all_objs]},
            headers={'content-type': 'application/json'},
            status_code=200)

run(host='localhost',
    port=8080,
    app=API,
    server='auto')
```

This code works fine, and I get api working as.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/students -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 74
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2016 15:55:23 GMT
Server: waitress
Status-Code: 200

{"data": [{"id": "7f6d18ec-bf24-4583-a06b-b9f55a4dc6e8", "name": "test"}, {"id": "7f6d18ec-bf24-4583-a06b-b9f55a4dc6e9", "name": "test1"}]}
```

Now I want to add pagging, and want to create api which has `limit` and `offset`.

I check [Paging Large Queries](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html#paging-large-queries) but it has no example with `Model`.

Then I change my api to:

```
# File: app.py
...
...
@API.get('/students')
def get_all_students():
    limit = request.query.limit
    offset = request.query.offset

    all_objs = StudentModel.all()
    if limit and offset:
        all_objs = all_objs[int(offset): int(offset+limit)]

    return HTTPResponse(
            body={'data': [x.__json__() for x in all_objs]},
            headers={'content-type': 'application/json'},
            status_code=200)
...
...
```

And call api as:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/students?limit=1&offset=0" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 74
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2016 16:12:00 GMT
Server: waitress
Status-Code: 200

{"data": [{"id": "7f6d18ec-bf24-4583-a06b-b9f55a4dc6e8", "name": "test"}]}
```

and

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/students?limit=1&offset=1" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 75
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2016 16:12:06 GMT
Server: waitress
Status-Code: 200

{"data": [{"id": "7f6d18ec-bf24-4583-a06b-b9f55a4dc6e9", "name": "test1"}]}
```

I get another solution using [has_more_pages](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.has_more_pages) and [start_fetching_next_page()](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.start_fetching_next_page)

```
from bottle import run
from bottle import Bottle, request, HTTPResponse

from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table

from models import StudentModel

API = Bottle()

# Create Connection
connection.setup(hosts=['192.168.99.100'],
                 default_keyspace='test',
                 protocol_version=3)

# Sync database table to create table in keyspace
sync_table(StudentModel)

@API.get('/students')
def get_all_students():
    limit = request.query.limit
    offset = request.query.offset

    page = int(request.query.page or 0)

    session = connection.get_session()
    session.default_fetch_size = 1

    objs = StudentModel.all()

    result = objs._execute(objs._select_query())

    data  = []
    count = 0
    while (not page or page > count) and result.has_more_pages:
        count += 1
        if page and page > count:
            result.fetch_next_page()
            continue

        data.extend(result.current_rows)
        result.fetch_next_page()
    all_objs = [StudentModel(**student) for student in data]

    return HTTPResponse(
            body={'data': [x.__json__() for x in all_objs]},
            headers={'content-type': 'application/json'},
            status_code=200)

run(host='localhost',
    port=8080,
    app=API,
    debug=True,
    server='auto')
```

From above 2 solution, which one is correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no efficient way to do pagination with CQLEngine. Using QuerySet slicing works, but be aware that previous pages will still be materialized internally in the result cache. So, this can lead to memory issues and it also affect the request performance. I've created a ticket to analyze a way to fill a single page at a time. You can watch the following ticket:

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-627

If you need an immediate efficient pagination support, I suggest to use the core driver instead of cqlengine.

Comment: Thanks Alan, can you give link for core driver?

Comment: Here is some docs about paging large queries: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html.

In the next release (3.7), you will be able to resume paging across executions paging_state. See https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-200

Comment: Alan, I gave same link in my question, but I am trying to find way to do this using `Model`

Comment: There is no other way to do it with a Model than what you are currently doing.

Comment: thanks Alan, we have to change our data rerive coding.

Comment: Alan, I get other code to do this, if you have time, can you please review this ?